# Do we need the endianess or multiarch tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[endianess](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/endianess) and [multiarch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiarch) don't seem to add to the questions (looking at what is there), and I don't feel it may be useful in its current form. I recommend getting rid of them.

Comment: Neither one has tag summaries or followers. No one would miss them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the tags are now cleaned up.